# same folder position gets passed every time

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, image-gallery

I created an image gallery app which was working fine. Then I tried to implement functionality to be able to select and delete images, one at a time. It worked but now same folder images get displayed on opening any folder. **For instance, doesn't matter whether I open folder 1 ,2 or 3 ,it will always display the images which are inside *folder 1***.I have tried my best to fix it but I couldn't fix it. How do I fix it ?Any suggestions ?

**ImageGallery.java**

```
public class ImageGallery extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ArrayList<Model_images> al_images = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean boolean_folder;
    Adapter_PhotosFolder obj_adapter;
    GridView gv_folder;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 100;
    int int_position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);
        gv_folder = (GridView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        obj_adapter = new Adapter_PhotosFolder(this,al_images,int_position);
        gv_folder.setAdapter(obj_adapter);

        final ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final ImageButton button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        final ImageButton button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        gv_folder.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotosActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("value",i);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        gv_folder.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,final int i, long l) {
                for (int j = 0; j < adapterView.getChildCount(); j++)
                    adapterView.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                // change the background color of the selected element
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button3.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageGallery.this);
                                builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete it ?");
                                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                        "Yes",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                File file = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(i));
                                                file.delete();
                                                al_images.remove(i);
                                                obj_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        });

                                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                        "No",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });

                                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                                alert11.show();
                            }
                        });

                return true;
            }
        });

        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ImageGallery.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) && (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale( ImageGallery.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( ImageGallery.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }else {
            Log.e("Else","Else");
            fn_imagespath();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Model_images> fn_imagespath() {
        al_images.clear();

        int int_position = 0;
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;

        String absolutePathOfImage;
        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        column_index_folder_name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            Log.e("Column", absolutePathOfImage);
            Log.e("Folder", cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));

            for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
                if (al_images.get(i).getStr_folder().equals(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name))) {
                    boolean_folder = true;
                    int_position = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    boolean_folder = false;
                }
            }


            if (boolean_folder) {

                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.addAll(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath());
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                al_images.get(int_position).setAl_imagepath(al_path);

            } else {
                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                Model_images obj_model = new Model_images();
                obj_model.setStr_folder(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));
                obj_model.setAl_imagepath(al_path);

                al_images.add(obj_model);


            }


        }


        for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("FOLDER", al_images.get(i).getStr_folder());
            for (int j = 0; j < al_images.get(i).getAl_imagepath().size(); j++) {
                Log.e("FILE", al_images.get(i).getAl_imagepath().get(j));
            }
        }
        obj_adapter = new Adapter_PhotosFolder(getApplicationContext(),al_images,int_position);
        gv_folder.setAdapter(obj_adapter);
        return al_images;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSIONS: {
                for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        fn_imagespath();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ImageGallery.this, "The app was not allowed to read or write to your storage. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**PhotosActivity.java:**

```
public class PhotosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int int_position;
    private GridView gridView;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    Adapter_PhotosFolder obj_adapter;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean boolean_folder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        final ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final ImageButton button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        final ImageButton button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        int_position = getIntent().getIntExtra("value", 0);
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, al_images, int_position);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        fn_imagespath();

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String abc = "file://" + al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                i.putExtra("folderPosition", int_position);
                i.putExtra("abc", abc);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                for (int j = 0; j < parent.getChildCount(); j++)
                    parent.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                // change the background color of the selected element
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button3.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotosActivity.this);
                                builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete it ?");
                                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                        "Yes",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                File file = new File( al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position));
                                                file.delete();
                                                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(PhotosActivity.this,new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                                                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                al_menu.remove(position);
                                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        });

                                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                        "No",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });

                                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                                alert11.show();
                            }
                        });

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    public ArrayList<Model_images> fn_imagespath() {
        al_menu.clear();

        int int_position = 0;
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;

        String absolutePathOfImage;
        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        cursor = getApplication().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        column_index_folder_name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            Log.e("Column", absolutePathOfImage);
            Log.e("Folder", cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));

            for (int i = 0; i < al_menu.size(); i++) {
                if (al_menu.get(i).getStr_folder().equals(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name))) {
                    boolean_folder = true;
                    int_position = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    boolean_folder = false;
                }
            }


            if (boolean_folder) {

                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.addAll(al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath());
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                al_menu.get(int_position).setAl_imagepath(al_path);

            } else {
                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                Model_images obj_model = new Model_images();
                obj_model.setStr_folder(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));
                obj_model.setAl_imagepath(al_path);

                al_menu.add(obj_model);


            }


        }


        for (int i = 0; i < al_menu.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("FOLDER", al_menu.get(i).getStr_folder());
            for (int j = 0; j < al_menu.get(i).getAl_imagepath().size(); j++) {
                Log.e("FILE", al_menu.get(i).getAl_imagepath().get(j));
            }
        }
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, al_menu,int_position);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return al_menu;
    }
}
```

**Adapter_PhotosFolder.java:**

```
public class Adapter_PhotosFolder extends ArrayAdapter<Model_images> {

    Context context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
    int int_position;


    public Adapter_PhotosFolder(Context context, ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu,int position) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_adapter__photos_folder, al_menu);
        this.al_menu = al_menu;
        this.context = context;
        this.int_position=position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.size() + "");
        return al_menu.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        if (al_menu.size() > 0) {
            return al_menu.size();
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_adapter__photos_folder, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tv_foldern = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder);
            viewHolder.tv_foldersize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder2);
            viewHolder.iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tv_foldern.setText(al_menu.get(position).getStr_folder());
        viewHolder.tv_foldersize.setText(al_menu.get(position).getAl_imagepath().size()+"");



        Glide.with(context).load("file://" + al_menu.get(position).getAl_imagepath().get(0))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(viewHolder.iv_image);


        return convertView;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_foldern, tv_foldersize;
        ImageView iv_image;


    }
```

Comment: `same folder images get displayed on opening any folder`. Can you explain this bit more what's exactly happening

Comment: For instance, doesn't matter whether I open folder 1 ,2 or 3 ,it will always display the images which are inside folder 1. @VivekMishra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have remove  `fn_imagespath();` line from PhotosActivity which gets you all the folder and there inside images. You are already fetching this inside ImageGallery Activity. No need to repeat this again.

Also You are seeing same images after click on every folder. This is because you are passing list of folder not the list of images inside the click folder.

Replace `getCount()` method with below code:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.size() + "");
        Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() + "");
        return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're telling Glide to only show you the image on the first position in the Adapter `...getAl_imagepath().get(0))` , replace 0 with the position of the selected item and it should work. Like this...

```
Glide.with(context).load("file://" + al_menu.get(position).getAl_imagepath().get(position))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(viewHolder.iv_image);
```

**Edit**: I would have add this to the comment, but its too long so i can't. In your `fn_imagespath()` function,  you're trying to access the loop counter outside its loop `int_position =i;`. Replace the entire loop with this...

```
 for (int i = 0; i < al_menu.size(); i++) {
                if (al_menu.get(i).getStr_folder().equals(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name))) {
                    //boolean_folder = true;

                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.addAll(al_menu.get(i).getAl_imagepath());
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                al_menu.get(i).setAl_imagepath(al_path);
                    break;
                } else {

                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                Model_images obj_model = new Model_images();
                obj_model.setStr_folder(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));
                obj_model.setAl_imagepath(al_path);

                al_menu.add(obj_model);
                //adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I just tried that, but It didn't work. on opening any folder, It displays the images which are inside the folder named  "Whatsapp Images"

Comment: Okay, try this...Replace `column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);` with `column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)`

Comment: I did what you wrote, and now it doesn't display any images. Logcat says **E/ADAPTER LIST SIZE: 0**